# Linking Data from One sheet into another on DropDown selection

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a Monthly Net Income/Expense Sheet.

I have a small manufacturing firm and based on orders we receive i want to add monthly Expense and Income.

I have created a small sheet

[image]

I have 3 sheets right now

- Orders List basically has Names of all orders i receive for example `Washing Unit`. I have defined a name so that it will be a drop down selection as can be seen in image as `Order Name`

Now my `Washing Unit` is EXACTLY same as this sheet except it doesn't have `Order Name`

I want to know if I select Washing Unit from Dropdown how can I link the entire Row data into my `Washing Unit` Sheet

e.g if I put Description and date,income and expense and then i select Washing Unit, it should be added as an entry in `Washing Unit` sheet and if I select None it will be removed from there

Comment: Have a look at `INDEX` and `SMALL` to return multiple rows. It quite a complicated array formula but if you do a web search you will find some useful tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you wish to extract data from a single cell in another sheet the best way to do it should be using the INDEX/MATCH worksheet function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some code of your own that you've tried? I suggest you try writing some then come back for help to perfect it.

Some hints:

- Use the worksheet_change event of sheet "Jan".
- To reliably identify rows to add or remove, you need another field in "Jan" and "Washing Unit" - let's call that "Order Number". It doesn't have to be fancy, it just has to uniquely identify each order.
- You set worksheet_change to check for changes in the "Order Name" column. If it finds one, it grabs the order number from the changed row and looks for that order number in the "Washing Unit" sheet.

  - If "Order Name" is "None" it deletes any rows with that order number from "Washing Unit".
  - If "Order Name" is "Washing Unit" and the order number is not found, it finds the first empty row in "Washing Unit" and adds the order there.

Edited to add:

That should be 'If "Order Name" is NOT "Washing Unit" it deletes any rows with that order number from "Washing unit".'

Changed because it occurred to me you might have other order names and from time to time you might need to correct an incorrect order name.

But you still need to write your own code!

Comment: i dont know VB coding and i am totally new in Excel, however i am learning , i am unable to edit VBasic Editor. I open it using Alt+F11 and then i cant click anywhere except change sheet name, no right click no left click.

Comment: Google "Getting started with Excel VBA" and pick one of the top results. Depending on your version you should enable the "Developer" menu and macros in the Trust Center. Any Getting Started site worth its salt will walk you through it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the which columns you have your data under, A, B, C etc. I'm not able to create something that will definately work on your sheet but the formula below is what myself and Variatus are suggesting you use.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Jan!$A$1:$E$1000,SMALL(IF(Jan!$D$2:$D$1000="Washing Unit",ROW(Jan!$A$2:$A$1000)),ROW(1:1)),2),"")
```

What you can create with a formula like this is a dynamic filtered version of the data you have on your sheet `Jan` so that as you add "Washing Unit" entries they will be autimatically listed on the `Washing Unit` sheet.

The fomula is looking at the whole table of data on sheet `Jan` and then it is comparing the data in column D `Jan!$D$2:$D$1000="Washing Unit"` to see if it contains "Washing Unit".  This formula would be placed at the top of sheet `Washing Unit` and it displays the first match `ROW(1:1)` and takes the data from the second column of the specified range ROW(1:1)),`2`),"") so you put the formula under the corresponding column in your `Washing Unit` sheet.

Once you have entered the formula you must use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to make it an array formula and add {}. You can then drag the formula down as many cells as you think you might need. (You'll see the data in the cells as you do this).

Then, go back to the top and copy the first cell over to the next column and change the number in the formula that specifies the column you want to extract data from ROW(1:1)),`2`),"") to `3` of the number that corresponds with your heading and again use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to add the curly brackets {} and auto-fill down again.

Repeat until you have all the columns you need.

It's not an easy formula and you need to remember the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to ensure that it works but you can have a go and see if you can get it working.